# Multiple cell selection in VBA using ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm starting in VBA and had to do a program that is able to retrieve value from a selected cell which will be used as reference.

I'm able to do it when I select one cell with the `Activecell` function and playing around with the `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value` etc.
However how to make the same thing while selecting multiple cells at the same time and be able to take the 1 cell value at a time and do `Activecell.Offset...` then identify the second cell value and retrieve the proper information and so on.

Using macro recorder I see that when I select multiple values it point to

```
Range("Y8,Y9,Y10,Y11").Select 'etc....
```

Thank you for your help and hope I've been precise enough on what I'm trying to do.

Many thanks
olivier

Comment: I am not sure I understood this. "However how to make the same thing while selecting multiple cell at the same time and be able to take the 1 select cell value and do acticecelloffset" - Does this mean you have multiple cells selected, but only want the value of one cell OR you have multiple cells selected and want every value out of the selected range?

Comment: Yes the idea is to have multiple cell selected and want every value out of the selected range. Many thanks EngJon for pointing the  blurring part of my question

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
```

or

```
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 2)
```

Then you can use it that way

```
For Each cell In Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
    Debug.Print cell.Value
Next cell
```

which is equivalent to

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Select ' or ActiveCell.Resize(1, 2).Select
For i = 0 To 1
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Offset(0, i)
Next i
```

Comment: Hello actually it does not do what i want to do

Comment: Hello actually it does not do what i want to do
actually i would like to be able to select at the same time multiple cells and retrieve for each of them the Cell content and do maybe a for each cell.selected then copy.paste.. next select cell copy past etc... do you have any ideas how to do it? many thanks for your help

Comment: @cyberol Let me rephrase the question to see if I understand it correctly. You want to do a loop on each cell of your selection but without having to select each of these cells one by one. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late and the OP probably has the solution but I think what he wants can be achieved by using `Selection` like:

```
Dim r As Range, c As Range

If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Set r = Selection Else Exit Sub

For Each c In r
    '/* put the code you want here */
    Debug.Print c.Address
    DebUg.Print c.Offset(0,1).Value
Next
```

Posting as answer just in case someone stumbled on the same problem/issue/requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to figure this out today and came across this post, so I thought I would update it with a link to where I found a simple answer.

I go this from https://excelchamps.com/vba/range-offset/

`Range(Range("A1").Offset(1, 1), Range("A1").Offset(5, 2)).Select`

So using the OP's desire to use ActiveCell as the starting location and an arbitrary range to select using an Offset, it would look something like this:

```
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(5, 2)).Select
```